# Glide loads same image in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-glide

It didn't happen to me before and I am trying to figure it out.

I am trying to display an image in a `RecyclerView`. The Images should be random every time, I use the following service: `https://picsum.photos/200/200/?random`

However, when I load the app, the `RecyclerView` displays the same image over and over again.

Just to be clear, I clear the holder:

```
        Glide.with(context).clear(holder.view.avatar)
        holder.view.image.setImageDrawable(null)
```

and then loading it

```
        Glide.with(context)
                .load("https://picsum.photos/200/200/?random")
                .into(holder.view.avatar)
```

Any idea what would be the problem?

Comment: add your adapter code.. because Glide are define single url then it load only this image if url change then it show other images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Glide caches the image using the url you provided.

Use Signature

```
Glide.with(yourFragment)
     .load(yourFileDataModel)
     .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
     .into(yourImageView);
```

or

disable caching by setting `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)`

or

use a trick https://picsum.photos/200/200/?temp={random string or number}, because extra query string not affecting your original url.

Comment: You are right. Seems that Glide keeps loading the same image if the URL doesn't change. I added some random numbers and now it's working.

Answer (score 4):

Use **`.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)`**

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load("https://picsum.photos/200/200/?random")
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
     .into(holder.view.avatar)
```